# Footable is not working for variable number of table in one single page

Tags: knockout.js, footable

I am trying to make **variable number of table** in a page with **knockOut**. Everything works fine but **footable** is not working. When I create **one single table** with knockOut, footable works fine. Here is my code for variable number of table with **knockOut**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: TablesData, afterRender: function(){}}">
<table data-bind="attr: { id: 'table'+t_id }" class="footable table">

    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Total Inspected</th>
        <th>QTY Certified</th>
        <th>Total Defects</th>
        <th data-hide="phone">Other Defects</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Rework Count</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Comment</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: t_bodyData, afterRender: function(){}} ">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: inspected"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: certified"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: rejected"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: other"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: rework"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: comment"></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Could you please tell me how can I make it working with footable?**

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two plunks I did that uses Knockout.js and Footable.

This one is a simple list of settings. (Keys and values)
http://plnkr.co/edit/VVsAiSNTvcnuCazQeuK2

This one has a list of Tasks and each Task can have a list of Tasks.  There is an issue that I'm trying to track down with how Footable redraws.  When redraw happens on a nested table, the rows disappear.
http://plnkr.co/edit/bXINbDBIMb0LbLitHGbl